# How to make jquery slider work for different data sets from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a query plugin slider which looks similar to facebook like photogrid,slider is working pretty well.My application has feature similar to facebook and linkedin in which there are posts.Each posts may have these pics slider,whose image paths from databse will be different for different posts havng different $msg_ids.This slider works only for one post.If I refresh the page all posts doesn't have the images,except one post.How to resolve that ?.
I want the slider to work for different:

```
 <div id="posts" class="post-image">
```

here is the code:
     
                    
    " />

```
               $(function() {


            $('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
                images:$.parseJSON($('#img-paths').val()),
                align: true,
                getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
            });

        });

    </script>


                  <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are mixing PHP, HTML and JavaScript in the same view, why not try this:

```
<div class="post-image">
    <?php $imagePathArray = explode(',',$uploads); ?>
    <div id="gallery7" ></div>
    <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
</div>
<footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
                images:
                    <?php foreach($imagePathArray as $data): ?>
                        "<?php echo $data ?>",
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                align: true,
                getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
            });
        });
    </script>
</footer>
```

This assumes that your images object in your imagesGrid method accepts each image path as a string, so if your $imagePathArray in PHP was:

```
array("/img/image1.png", "/img/image2.php", "/img/image3.png");
```

The relevant bit of your script should essentially be:

```
$('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
    images:"/img/image1.png","/img/image2.png", "/img/image3.png",
    align: true,
    getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
});
```

I hope this helps,

Shaun.

Comment: since its multiple image, i cant use foreach like that i guess. a post may contain multiple image as well. @Shaun Bebbers

Comment: For me the slider is working ,but for only a single post ,which was previously uploaded.Since there are other posts which is having different sets of images and $message.

Comment: Sorry, the `images:` parameter in the object has confused me as it's a plural. I guess you could wrap a `{}` around the foreach loop, like `images:{<?php foreach($imagePathArray as $data): ?>"<?php echo $data ?>",<?php endforeach; ?>}` which will achieve the same results as your example. If you are having difficulties with your $_POST data, have a look at its contents with `<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, 1) . '</pre>';`

Comment: not that post .. its like the post u update in facebook or linkdein. that post i meant . not the $_POST

Comment: anyways .. thank for your help @Shaun i got my solution ..It can be achieved as below" to number id of the hidden input. In this case change <input id="img-paths" to <input id="img-path-7", also don't forget to change the javascript $('#img-paths').val() to $('#img-path-7').val(). Just number every hidden input accordingly"